# Heat issues on 11.10 beta?

Tags: 11.10, overheating

I am running an old Gateway laptop (7330gz) with 1 gig of RAM and 80 gig HDD, when I went to try 11.04 I found myself overheating frequently and ended up returning to 10.10.

Has anyone noticed any problems with overheating in the 11.10 beta 1?

Answer (score 4):

There is a known bug in Linux 2.6.38 and newer kernels that cause bigger power consumption and more heat. Here is related Ubuntu bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/760131

Here is link to my article about a workaround that was discovered by fantastic people from Phoronix:

http://www.techytalk.info/linux-kernel-2-6-38-2-6-39-power-regression-workaround/

I would post link to original Phoronix article but I'm not allowed to post more than two links here and I think you'll benefit most from these two. Inside TechyTalk article you'll find link to Phoronix article with detailed explanation and two ways to apply workaround that works for most people but the safe bet would be to stay on 10.10 like most people until at least kernel 3.2 that could bring permanent fix.

Comment: @Marko - Thanks for the quick response, I guess I should have been more specific.  I thought I read that 11.10 would be running the 3.2 kernel.

Comment: @beachbuddah - the work to fix this bug hasn't started yet so I don't believe Linux 3.2 will fix it for good. We can only hope because as I've heard it isn't really easy to fix so no one wants to touch it.