# Dell inspiron N5010 with ATI overheating

Tags: 11.10, dell, overheating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dell Inspiron N5010 overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83383/dell-inspiron-n5010-overheating)

I have a Dell Inspiron N5010 with ATI Radeon 5470 1GB graphics card. I am dual booting windows 7 and ubuntu 11.10 64bit and for the graphics card I am using open source graphics drivers which are preinstalled.

After installing ubuntu I notice that the laptop is getting overheated while ubuntu is running, but with windows it is ok. The temperature is always over 58 degree Celsius and laptop fan is always running. Could this be because of the graphics card? Please help me fix the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/83383/dell-inspiron-n5010-overheating